# Bad/strange USB device issue: failed to shutdown/restart

Tags: linux, usb, devices, shutdown

On a fresh Arch Linux installation with Intel i7 processor and an Nvidia graphics card, I noticed during boot log messages related to a usb device filled the screen before it reached the graphical login (gdm).

During the time of this issue, the computer would fail to reboot/shutdown with logs showing that the system was trying to stop a udev process (sent sigterm signals that probably was ignored or something like that?), forcing me to do a hard shutdown (hold down power button).

Looking at `dmesg`/`journalctl` logs, something strange was going on with some usb device, so I decided to see what would happen if I unplugged half of my USB devices.

I unplugged all speakers (headset and usb speakers) and my webcam, and suddenly the strange logs disappeared from boot and the computer could shutdown fine.
Even stranger, was that when I plugged everything back in again, everything worked fine as if nothing had happened as well.

Feeling a bit suspicious of my usb devices (tl;dr paranoia), I decided to unplug my webcam and leave it that way.

Is this issue something to worry about? I don't think this is an issue that should happen randomly until I unplug devices, as it was consistently failing to restart/shutdown until I unplugged usb devices.

Not sure if these logs could be helpful, but:

- [The dmesg log that I got during this issue can be seen here.](http://hastebin.com/luwurefado.vhdl)
- [The dmesg log I get now with no issue restarting/shutting-down is here.](http://hastebin.com/avipusowic.vhdl)

If you need more detail, or have an idea of what's going on, please don't hesitate to post.

EDIT: The reason why I'm leaving my webcam unplugged is because it is the newest device I have on my system. My speakers I've had for a while and they've worked great. I suspect it's just a malfunctioning webcam, but I would like another's opinion of it.